# Assigning string as a variable

Tags: r, eval

Is it possible to assign a string containing variable names to a variable in R?

For example imagine I have the string `"log(p_n) + log((1 - p_n)) + log(p_n * p_b) + log(p_n * (1 - p_b)) + log((1 - p_n) * p_g)"`. I'd like to make this function:

```
formula_function = function(p_n, p_b, p_g){
  x <- log(p_n) + log((1 - p_n)) + log(p_n * p_b) + log(p_n * (1 - p_b)) + log((1 - p_n) * p_g)
  return(x)
}
```

I have a function which generates the formula strings and I'm just copy-pasting them by hand at the moment, is there a more 'program-y' way of doing it?

Comment: The trickiest part would seem to be determining the parameter order for your function. Are you sure you really need a function? How will you call the function if you aren't sure what parameters it takes. There may be better strategies like just evaluating an expression rather than creating a function but it's not clear exactly what your requirements are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) body** Assuming you know the parameters:

```
x <- "log(p_n) + log((1 - p_n)) + log(p_n * p_b) + log(p_n * (1 - p_b)) + log((1 - p_n) * p_g)"

f <- function(p_n, p_b, p_g) {}
body(f) <- parse(text = x)
f
## function (p_n, p_b, p_g) 
## log(p_n) + log((1 - p_n)) + log(p_n * p_b) + log(p_n * (1 - p_b)) +
##    log((1 - p_n) * p_g)
```

**2) as.function** The gsubfn package has a function for converting formulas to functions.  The order of the formal arguments will be in the order encountered in x or you can specify the order.  Convert the string to a formula using reformulate and then use as.function.

```
library(gsubfn)

# args are in order encountered
f <- as.function(reformulate(x))
f
## function (p_n, p_b, p_g) 
## log(p_n) + log((1 - p_n)) + log(p_n * p_b) + log(p_n * (1 - p_b)) + 
##    log((1 - p_n) * p_g)

# specify order of args
f <- as.function(reformulate(x, "p_n + p_g + p_b"))
f
## function (p_n, p_g, p_b) 
## log(p_n) + log((1 - p_n)) + log(p_n * p_b) + log(p_n * (1 - p_b)) + 
##     log((1 - p_n) * p_g)
```

**3) match.funfn** gsubfn also has match.funfn that is like match.fun in R except it also translates arguments passed as formulas to functions.  e.g.

```
library(gsubfn)

myfun <- function(a, b, c, fun) {
  f <- match.funfn(fun)
  f(a, b, c)
}
myfun(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, reformulate(x, "p_n + p_g + p_b"))
## [1] -11.82901
```

**4) fn$** gsubfn also provides fn which when prefixed to an arbitrary function will interpret formulas as functions.  See the help file `?fn` for details.  Note that sapply was not specially written for this but it works anyways.

```
library(gsubfn)

fn$sapply(1:3, ~ x^2)
## [1] 1 4 9
```